# Using a function to generate a docstring in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to be able to programatically define a docstring for one of my functions in clojure.

For example, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
(defn my-function
    (str "Here are some numbers " (range 10))
    []
    (println "This function does nothing right now."))
```

However, when I attempt to do this, I get "Parameter decleration str should be a vector". Is this just not possible in clojure or is there some sneaky way to do this? It would be useful to me to programatically generate parts of the docstring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, it's definitely possible. The thing you're running into here is that `defn` (or rather, the `def` special form that it expands to) attaches a docstring to the symbol iff the argument in second place is a string.

You can circumvent this by setting the `:doc` metadata yourself.

```
(defn ^{:doc (apply str "Here are some numbers " (range 10))} my-function
   []
   (println "This function does nothing right now."))
```

Or potentially by writing your own macro - but I think the above is the most straightforward way of doing it.